# How can I use SQL Query to attain a complete address from a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a database with addresses and postcodes. I need to just get the complete address. How can I do this in a SQL Query? I tried row count, that did not work as some people can move a couple of times. The data is in the below format, I want the none matching records from the table.

[image]

```
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------------+----------+-------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|  ID   | Percode |   ITEM   |        MoveSTART        | TRACKEND |  PID  | REFERENCE |              TRACKVALUE              |
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------------+----------+-------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| 14051 |       0 | ADDRESS  | 2011-03-24 00:00:00.000 | NULL     | 10000 | NULL      | 1 test  High Street  Avening, test   |
| 14050 |       0 | POSTCODE | 2014-05-27 00:00:00.000 | NULL     | 10000 | NULL      | S12  8DU                             |
| 14049 |       0 | POSTCODE | 2011-03-24 00:00:00.000 | NULL     | 10000 | NULL      | s12 8LU                              |
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------------+----------+-------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

i want to return only ID -14050, as the other 2 are complete address

SELECT     ID, Percode, ITEM, MoveSTART, TRACKEND, PID, VALUE
FROM            tyeaddtest
where  MoveSTART not in (select MoveSTART from tyeaddtest where ITEM in ('ADDRESS')) and ITEM = 'POSTCODE'

Some i have returned with the above query, but similar to the above table i cant return them with this query

Comment: welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Don't post links to images of data.  Instead you can generate an [ASCII table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/).  and show what you have attempted.  thanks

Comment: You have two POSTCODE rows for the same PID, but they have different MoveStart dates. I'd guess the three of those are the unique combination? So you'll have to find the latest MoveStart for a given PID, either here or in some other data, and then only select the rows for a given MoveStart and PID pair.

Comment: Or if that's wrong, and there should only be one POSTCODE per PID, you'll need to talk to whoever owns the data about cleaning up the database, and then add unique constraints so it can't happen again.

Comment: And what precisely do you mean by the "none matching records" please?

Comment: Yes PID and Movestart are the same so i have extra Postcode lines i need only return all the onces that dont have an address in Item

Comment: What database are you using please? SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, something else?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes PID and Movestart are the same so i have extra Postcode lines i need only return all the onces that dont have an address in Item

Here's a slightly inelegant way of returning any PID and MoveStart combination that doesn't have exactly one address and postcode:

```
select pid, movestart,
    (select count(*) from tyeaddtest a where a.pid = t.pid and a.movestart = t.movestart and item = 'ADDRESS') as addresses,
    (select count(*) from tyeaddtest p where p.pid = t.pid and p.movestart = t.movestart and item = 'POSTCODE') as postcodes
  from tyeaddtest t
  group by pid, movestart
  having (select count(*) from tyeaddtest a where a.pid = t.pid and a.movestart = t.movestart and item = 'ADDRESS') != 1
      or (select count(*) from tyeaddtest p where p.pid = t.pid and p.movestart = t.movestart and item = 'POSTCODE') != 1
```

If you can use common table expressions with your database then you could make this a bit nicer and avoid having to repeat the subqueries, e.g. this is the syntax for SQL Server:

```
with AddressAndPostcodeCounts as (
  select pid, movestart,
    (select count(*) from tyeaddtest a where a.pid = t.pid and a.movestart = t.movestart and item = 'ADDRESS') as addresses,
    (select count(*) from tyeaddtest p where p.pid = t.pid and p.movestart = t.movestart and item = 'POSTCODE') as postcodes
  from tyeaddtest t
  group by pid, movestart
)
select * from AddressAndPostcodeCounts where addresses != 1 or postcodes != 1
```

but you havent told us which database you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.PID, (SELECT TOP 1 t2.VALUE FROM the_table_name t2 
WHERE t2.item='ADDRESS' AND t2.PID = t1.PID ORDER BY MoveSTART DESC) as ADDRESS 
from the_table_name t1
```

If you're using MySQL you need to replace TOP 1 with LIMIT 1 at the end of the subquery

Comment: they are some people who have move couple time so they will have 2 address so this will not work i have mamnged to get some of the postcode but still got some to get as the above will not be returned

Comment: The subquery will only return the most recent address.